# lme() - returns incorrect Residual (within group) variance

Tags: r, residuals, lme4-nlme

I tried to use `lme()` to get intercept and `residual` variance values using a very simple dataset with just 2 values x and y. There are multiple values of 'y' for every value of 'x' and they are stored in a data frame that has 2 columns: x, y with x having duplicate/repeat values. Here is the dataset that I used:

```
x <-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8)

y<-c(23,56,34,12,13,54,34,78,34,24,45,11,92,37,82,17,26,39,32,56,43,27,83,58,32,67,45,34,67,34,36,32)

lmeDemoFrame<- data.frame(x= factor(x), y=y)
```

I then generated the model using:

```
library(nlme)
lmeDemo <- lme(y~1, data=lmeDemoFrame, random=~1|x, subset=! is.na(y))
answr<- as.numeric(VarCorr(lmeDemo)[,1])
```

'answr' returns intercept variance as 2.433034e-06 but the `residual variance` returned is 461.7974.

I understand the low intercept variance (between group variation) value since for all the x-axis values, there is minimal variance in y-axis values but why did `lme()` return such a high residual variance?

All of the values used for y range between 10 to 85. Is it because of the difference within the same x-value, e.g. for x=2, we have y = 13, 54, 34, 78 & for x=3, I have y= 92,37,82, 17?

This is not a programming question. I am very new to mixed models and hence want a simple explanation of the logic behind the high residual variance that I get for this dataset and for other datasets that I use.
Any prompt feedback about the logic would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue understanding the output has nothing to do with mixed models in this case. From your post you seem to expect that you get the **residual standard deviation** as an output, but what you get is the ***residual standard variance***.

The residual variance is the square of the residual standard deviation, this means a value of about 460 is totally reasonable. For example, just looking at your x = 2 values they have a standard deviation of 27.78, so the variance is that squared -> 771.58.